# flask application http request method showing error

Tags: flask

so I was studying flask and how to request http methods.I am able to run html.But when i request url they are showing error.please guide me.code is attached herewith.Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head> sub </head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:5000/submit",method="path">
        <p>Enter name</p>
        <p> <input type="text",name="nm" /> </p>
        <p><input type="submit",value="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


from flask import Flask,url_for,redirect,request
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/page/<name>')
def display(name):
    return 'Hello %s'%name

@app.route('/submit',methods=['POST','GET'])
def submit():
    if request.methods=='POST':
        user=request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('display',name=user))
    else:
        user=request.args.get('nm')
        return redirect(url_for('display',name=user))

    if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `url_for` template tag for mentioning url in html and also method should be POST and remove those `,` in your html.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('sumbit') }}" method="POST">
```

Always .format for string operations

```
return "Hello {}".format(name)
```